# TypeError: Describe is not a function. When running Selenium Test on Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, automation, gitlab-ci

My automation test runs without issue on my local but while trying to run my test on GITLAB CI, I encountered this error.

[image]

```
Gitlab-ci.yml

image: markadams/chromium-xvfb-js:7

stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:   paths:
    - node_modules/
     before_script: 
- chmod 0777 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha

install_dependencies:   stage: build   script:
    - npm install
    - npm install mocha -g

test_with_lab:   stage: test   script: npm test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you require `describe` function `var describe = require ('mocha').describe` in `test.js` file. If you require `describe` function in `test.js`, delete it, because `describe` function is setup by mocha.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are testing via mocha, you have to run your tests using the mocha command instead of the node executable *npm*.